# Bypassing other clicks on 'drawend'

Tags: openlayers-3

I have features that may react to clicks.

```
vm.map.on('singleclick', function (event) { ... }
```

At some point, I need to draw a shape using interaction and do something on `'drawend'` event.

**Problem:** If, on `'drawend'`, mouse pointer is over one of the 'clickable' features, the feature react as if it was clicked. Which should not happen since that click's purpose should be only to end interaction drawing.

(Context includes Angular.js.)

Already tried:
- Having a boolean value that can accessed by both event and set it to true/false depending on need. But it looks like `'drawend'` happens before `vm.map.on('singleclick'` and so the click is still 'forwarded' to the underlying feature.
- Registering/Unregistering `'singleClick'` event according to need. Similar result as other tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improve what you tried like this:

set a boolean value : isDrawing = true;
ondrawend : setTimeout(function(){isDrawing = false;},100);

when singleclick happens, your boolean is still true :)

Comment: Thank you. I just had to put 1000 rather than 100.